# How to convert S-video to YPbPr?

Tags: converter, video, tv

I want to connect devices which output S-video (Y/C) to my TV, which only has YPbPr component inputs. One of them outputs PAL (European) while the other outputs PAL-M.

One way to do this would be to chain video decoder and video encoder ICs, which gives me flexibility on the color systems but an AD/DA conversion seems unnecessary to me as I understand that I just need to separate the Pb/Pr signals from the incoming C signal. Also this seems like a fun project to undertake.

How could I go about doing this separation? Are there any ICs to help me out on this?

Comment: @dandavis A simple google search did not yield any useful results, so I decided to ask here.

Comment: http://www.ambery.com/costorgrgbco.html

Comment: @BruceAbbott During my previous searches this was the only converter I could find, but there were some issues, first it's quite pricey, plus international FedEx shipping... then according to its description it seems to do that AD/DA conversion I wanted to avoid (because it scales the image). I actually have one composite/S-video to RGB adapter here but the output quality is actually worse than using composite directly, so I am afraid of investing that amount of money on a ready-made scaler again... I also want to avoid delays introduced by the analog-digital and digital-analog conversions..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should be feasible with an old analog PAL decoder chip. With a quick search, I found the TDA8391 chip that might work for you (you would only use a part of that chip).

Comment: Yes, looks like it. Reading its datasheet I was able to refine my search terms, phrases like "color decoder", "chroma decoder", "color-difference output" or **"TV processor"** seem to yield the best results. Searching for "TV processor" I've been able to find lots of ICs! Thanks.

Comment: If you are successful with your project, with a non-obsolete IC, could you please consider posting a follow-up with the chip you used?

Comment: Unfortunately the non-obsolete ICs I could find only output digital video. But I will document the process and follow-up with the steps and hurdles.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a video decoder plus a video encoder in a back to back config. With this config you can do it 100% sure : ADV7180 + ADV739X.